# Form / digsig.sty: How to add a 'value' into a digsiffield

Tags: hyperref, forms, adobe

**I use digsig.sty from Martin Lottermoser
http://home.htp-tel.de/lottermose2/tex/dist/digsig.sty**

---

Is it possible to add a 'value' into a digsigfield like into a TextField?

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{digsig} 

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
{\color{red}\fbox{\noindent\digsigfield{0.5\textwidth}{10cm}{test}}  }\\
Please add your picture here!
\end{Form}
\end{document
```

}

Comment: Use \raisebox to raise the text.